# What view is being passed in for the on Click Activity?

Tags: android, view, onclick

```
    public void upVote(View view) {
```

}
In this onClick set up above what view is being passed in?Also what does this code mean below? what view am i getting?

```
        CharSequence VoteUpId = ((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view.getParent()).getChildAt(1)).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this onClick set up above what view is being passed in?

It's the view that received the `onClick` event.

> Also what does this code mean below?

1. Get the view parent, and cast it to `RelativeLayout`.
2. Get first child view from this layout.
3. Cast this child to `TextView`
4. Get the text from this view and assign it to `VoteUpId` variable.

Comment: So How do I do all of this without creating an on click event ?

Comment: Like if I create another method such as public void upVote(View view ){

Comment: is that going to refer to an eventlistener or can i just pass a view in instead also how would I pass a view int?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the context. What are you trying to achieve? This is java, you can call every method you want :) If you create that upVote method it will not refer to any event listener, you will have to call it on your own and pass a view you want. I hope I answered the question..